# Is an html link relative only if the value begins with http?

Tags: html, hyperlink

For example the html

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com">free e-mail and news</a>
```

Is treated relative but

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">free e-mail and news</a>
```

links to [yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com). Is that all there is to it, the only way a link is absolute is if it starts with http or https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Please Refer to the below link, which explains the Hyperlinks syntax.

[HTML BASICS: HYPERLINK SYNTAX – ABSOLUTE, RELATIVE AND ROOT-RELATIVE](http://designisphilosophy.com/tutorials/html-basics-hyperlink-syntax-absolute-relative-and-root-relative/)

> Absolute hyperlinks are complete addresses that contain all the
>   elements of a URL. They always start with some version of http://
>   followed by the domain name (for example, www.designisphilosophy.com)
>   and optionally a page/folder. Absolute hyperlinks are used when
>   linking to pages outside of the current site that have a different
>   domain name.

Answer (score 1):

A URL is said to be in `absolute` form if it starts with any access `protocol`.
General syntax is:

```
protocol://hostname/other_information
```

Following are some examples of absolute URLS:

1. http://example.org/absolute/URI/with/absolute/path/to/resource.txt
2. ftp://example.org/resource.txt
3. urn:issn:1535-3613
4. jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true
5. mailto:ravi@somedomain.com
6. jar:file:/home/username/Desktop/some.jar

A Relative URL is with respect to the current path to a location either on the browser, console, or workspace.

For example
If you are on `http://yahoo.com/` page and any link points to `/mail` rather than `http://mail.yahoo.com` then it is in relative to the yahoo web path.

Answer (score 0):

> An absolute link defines a specific location of the Web file or
>   document including: the protocol to use to get the document, the
>   server to get it from, the directory it is located in, and the name of
>   the document itself. Below is an example of an absolute link:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/pagename.html"></a>
```

> With a relative link, the search engine spiders and browsers already
>   know where the current document is located. Thus, if you link to
>   another document in the same directory, you will not need to write out
>   the full URL. Only the file name is necessary. Below is an example of
>   a relative link:

```
<a href="pagename.html"></a>
```

[**Reference.**](http://www.webpronews.com/absolute-vs-relative-links-which-is-better-for-the-search-engines-2004-08)